# Java - Is it possible to see if a string I'm bringing in from a text field and converting to a double is less than a certain number?

Tags: java

I need to make sure that the value entered in the text field is less than 72. I already have it set up to make sure that it's a double.

```
    if(age.getText().isEmpty() || !age.getText().matches("\\d{0,2}") || age.getText()<=72) {
        // gives user alert error }
```

I know what I have doesnt work with the <=72, but is there a way I can make it work? I haven't really found one when I was looking.

Comment: The obvious answer is to convert it to a double, then check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't checking that the number is a `double` in the code you pasted - nor should you need to.  You can use something like :

`Integer.parseInt(...)` which takes a String and returns an int.  Then you can store that result in a variable and replace the entire predicate with :

```
int ageInYears = Integer.parseInt(...) // you'll need to wrap this in a try/catch

if(ageInYears >= 72) {
   //handle the old fogey
}
```

If you have to use a `double`, look at [Double.parseDouble(String s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))

Comment: If you really feel like you need a double, there's a parseDouble method you can search for.  I would argue its unnecessary though ...

Comment: It needs to be a double because of the way it's calculated later in the code it's easier as a double than as an int.